# Advanced Logging module can't be installed in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, iis-8, iis-advanced-logging

I am trying to get the Advanced Logging module installed into IIS 8.5. When I check on Microsoft's official site - **https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging** all download links seem broken actually. The only way is to use Web Platform Installer but it gives the following error:

```
Exception: System.Net.WebException: Url 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/6/5/96594C39-9918-466C-AFE0-920737351987/AdvancedLogging64.msi' returned HTTP status code: 404
```

Is there a way how I can achieve this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/enhanced-logging-for-iis85 For IIS 8.5 and above, you should use Enhanced Logging instead.